# Fetching Core Data row by name?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm currently on a new project an encountering some difficulties regrind fetch requests in Swift.

Basically my setup looks as following.

Entity "Plants" - name, info, plant2 (placeholder so far)
Entity "PlantLog" - name, date, erg, cmt, fertilizer

I already have TableView with "Plants" in it and can update Plant Information such as Name, Info and "Plant2". When I also have a button called "Add Log" in which the name of the plant is given to the new View:

```
 if segue.identifier == "addLog"
    {

        var existingPlant: String = textFieldName.text
        let IVC: AddPlantViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddPlantViewController
        IVC.name = existingPlant


    }
```

This works perfectly. Also the saving to the PlantLog Entity with Name and the other stuff. But now comes my problem --> When I click on Save it should also perform a segue action in which it Updates a TableView for the Plant where only the Log Entries for "name" lets call it "Pachira" are displayed and where the segue "Show e.g. Push" gives the values for the PlantDetail page.

```
@IBAction func testFetch(sender: AnyObject) {


    var error: NSError?
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Plants")
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let contxt: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let fetchResults = contxt.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", name)


    //fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

     // var data: NSManagedObject = fetchResults as! NSManagedObject
   // labelName.text = predicate


}
```

This was just a test if I could fetch the row with the Name "Pachira" but I can't find a solution to fetch "Pachira" together with "Info" and "Plant2" from my Core Data.

Comment: Don't you even get record for "Pachira" ? Or the whole information about Pachira you are not getting??

Comment: Nope I dont get "Pachira" The App crashes

Comment: why this line `fetchRequest.predicate = predicate` is commented? It is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give no information about the crash, but from the look of those commented out lines, you are having problems accessing the results of your fetch.  First, you need to set the predicate for the fetch request *before* you execute the fetch.  Then, the return value from `executeFetchRequest` is an array - even if there is only one matching object.  So rearrange your fetch as follows:

```
var error: NSError?
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Plants")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", name)
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let contxt: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
let fetchResults = contxt.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)
// You should check whether fetchResults is nil, and if so log the error. 
//  You should also ensure that at least one object is returned.
let object = fetchResults![0]
println("\(object)")
```

Comment: I will Test and comment asap

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help.
My output now say:

```
 data: { info = TEST; name = Pachira; Plant2 = TEST; }
```

This would be perfect. But how to retrieve a value. When I say "object.info" it says that object does not have a child called info...but it is there.

Edit:

How stupid from me...I forgot to do:

```
  let test = object.valueForKey("name")
```

Now the Output says "Optional(Pachira)".
How can I get rid of that?

Edit no2:

Again I was very stubborn not seeing my error...of course I must convert my Array value to string...

Thank you!